# Glassfish 4 admin console read-only account

Tags: glassfish, payara

Is it possible to create a read-only account to logon admin console. I would like to let someone to logon admin console with read-only permission only.

Answer (score 0):

Not in GlassFish, but there is an open enhancement request to add user roles to the admin console for Payara Server:

https://github.com/payara/Payara/issues/1600